# Abnormal behavior of markAllAsTouched() in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[image: enter image description her]

I have set the supplier name field to required but when I submit my form, I get the correct error "form is invalid" but it didn't highlight the mandatory field with a red border. When I click on another field, such as the preferred checkbox or the supplier name itself, the supplier name field is highlighted as a mandatory field and the red border appears properly.

[image]

```
`if (this.mainForm.invalid) {
      obj.messageType = MessageMode.Error;
      obj.message = 'Form is Invalid';
      obj.hideInterval = 0;
      this.supplierProfileInteractionService.messagePromptStateChanged([obj]);
      this.mainForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return false;
    }`
```

Here is the code of TS File

```
      `<div class="form-control">
          <div formGroupName="profile">
              <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label>Supplier Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="name" maxlength="256" />
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
       </div>`
```

Here is the HTML Code

Does anyone know why this behavior is abnormal?
I am using angular version 14

Comment: I think you have to update de validity of the form using updateValueAndValidity method

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot.

this.form.get(' clientName').updateValueAndValidity();